# Why WSL2 network performance does degrade with big files?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

WSL network transfer rate decreases when transferring big files.

To reproduce, you can try to upload a file in the order of 100MB or larger.

**Example**

From Windows Host, a Windows 11 system, transfer of this file

```
04/10/2023  20:54       939,587,072 en-ai-ubi8-apache2-py311.tgz
```

to a remote system using SCP is measured at **1714.0 kB/s**:

[image]

From WSL version 2, in the same host,

```
D:\>wsl -l -v
  NAME                   STATE           VERSION
* CentOS                 Running         2
  docker-desktop-data    Stopped         2
  docker-desktop         Stopped         2
```

Same transfer **from WSL** is measured at nearly same speed at the beginning, but then quickly the transfer rate is decreased down to **37 KB/s!**

[image]

The problem is now well known and reported in github

https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/8171

Needless to say, this problem affects any software dealing with large files, typical examples include: software package managers, docker push/pull was unusable, ftp servers, etc.

Comment: Please present more evidence, your system specs, your network configuration, and phrase your post as a question (right now it is phrased as a statement which makes it difficult to tell whether you are asking something). Also, it's OK to answer your own question, but this is a not-question that appears to exist solely to give you a place to present some possibly helpful information. That doesn't make this valid. Present a problem, and if you have an answer, present an actual answer. This site isn't really a bulletin board.

Comment: Yes, sure, I was in a hurry and just wanted to bring attention to this problem, since I didn't find a solution in StackOverflow/StackExchange so far  .

Comment: Cool, thanks for improving that. I've retracted my own close vote and upvoted the question and answer. You should be able to mark your answer as the correct answer too, using the checkmark icon next to it, which will help the system understand your post better too.

Comment: This doesn't read like a question.

Comment: Ok, the question is why it is so slow and how to fix this slowness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is related with the way that data is splitted into network packets. Different networks have different MTU (Maximum Transmission Unit).

For different networks, there are different MTU sizes:
Ethernet: 1500 bytes; PPPoE: 1492 bytes; ATM (AAL5): 9180 bytes; FDDI: 4470 bytes; PPP: 576 bytes, etc.

The ethernet adapter in the linux system sees a virtual ethernet adapter, managed by Windows.

While I ignore the details, I suspect that there's some problem related in the fragmentation of data by the different network stacks (TCP/IP stack in Linux, TCP/IP stack in Windows and the card adapter).

The workaround consists of enabling LSO in the virtual adapter, which basically allows sending larger data frames to the lower layer (network card device driver, in case of a "real" adapter, but in the case of a virtual adapter, data goes first to [Hyper-V virtual switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v-virtual-switch/hyper-v-virtual-switch) and then to the physical adapter...).

There are a couple of bugs reported. Here are some links:

[Very slow network speed on WSL2 · Issue #4901](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4901)

[Very slow network speeds #8171 - microsoft/WSL](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/8171)

[low internet speed in WSL 2](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/low-internet-speed-in-wsl-2/21524829-18be-4611-bb5f-cabccd2cae31)

[WSL 2 — How To Fix Download Speed | by Chris Townsend](https://townsyio.medium.com/wsl2-how-to-fix-download-speed-3edb0c348e29)

Etc.

Note that Windows 11 does not show virtual adapters so I had to apply the workaround using Powershell as Administrator:

```
 PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Enable-NetAdapterLso -Name vEthernet* -IncludeHidden -IPv4
 PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Enable-NetAdapterLso -Name vEthernet* -IncludeHidden -IPv6                                           PS
```

[As far as I know, my setup does not use switch embedded teaming LBFO/SET technologies]

Comment: I have completely rewritten this answer, while keeping the core (the workaround).